# RestKit map object with url as attribute

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I have the following JSON which I like to map in restkit.

```
{
 "objects": [
     {"name": "John Doe",
      "contacts": [
         "/url/to/contact/1/",
      ]
     }
}
```

Is it possible in RestKit to map this directly, combined with Core Data, in which case if the contact with id 1 exists do not follow the url to retrieve the contact.
What is the best way to make this work?

Comment: this isn't valid JSON.

Comment: It is made with django-tastypie

Comment: swoei, the value of contacts is a list of strings. See if you can make it a list of dictionaries. Then, follow [these instructions](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping) to do the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you should dehydrate your contacts so that you get the id instead of a url, restkit map relationships with id not url. Then follow this post : [RestKit Object Mapping Relationships without KVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318565/restkit-object-mapping-relationships-without-kvc)